# Allow duplicates in SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I created a view for some tax reporting. During my second validation, I found that the view was eliminating duplicates (the view is based on another view if that matters).

When I run the query that is used to create the view, it does not eliminate duplicates.

Is there a way to create the view and force it to keep the duplicate records? There is no other value in the main view that is makes it unique.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. There is no magic in a view that causes to automatically suppress duplicates. Can you share your SQL and your CREATE VIEW statement?

Comment: Be careful here. You say you created this view based on another view. If that means you have nested views you should reconsider. It seems perfectly logical but for performance it is a killer. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: The other view probably has a distinct clause in it. Duplicates don't disappear by themselves so somewhere in the chain dups are being eliminated.

Comment: You can say whatever you want.  What matters is the query.  Where's the query???  We can't help you unless we see what's wrong with your query.  A bunch of sentences do nothing to help you.

Comment: Might there be a mixup between `union` and `union all`?

Comment: No way the view and query used to create the view return different results.

Comment: @Eric  He claims the query does not produce incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted the query. The problem was I had one plain union without the all - that removed all duplicates.